# (cmd) I want to use taskkill to deny me from using a program for X time

Tags: windows

I did some research but its really hard when you dont know much about programming I think... My idea is to repeat taskkill on a program every second for x time. This is for self-control, if you are wondering why I want this. Can you help me out?

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself?

Comment: No, because I only know the taskkill part.